# httpUrlClient post to auto login to a website

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

I'm struggling where can I find correct parameter to put Username and Password in.

Here is a http code I can get from the website.

```html
<h1>Login</h1>

<p>Please Login</p>

<div class="form">
<form id="login-form" action="/arkyii/index.php/site/login" method="post">
 <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

 <div class="row">
  <label for="LoginForm_username" class="required">Username <span class="required">*</span></label>  <input name="LoginForm[username]" id="LoginForm_username" type="text" />  <div class="errorMessage" id="LoginForm_username_em_" style="display:none"></div> </div>

 <div class="row">
  <label for="LoginForm_password" class="required">Password <span class="required">*</span></label>  <input name="LoginForm[password]" id="LoginForm_password" type="password" />  <div class="errorMessage" id="LoginForm_password_em_" style="display:none"></div>  
 </div>

 <div class="row rememberMe">
  <input id="ytLoginForm_rememberMe" type="hidden" value="0" name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" /><input name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" id="LoginForm_rememberMe" value="1" type="checkbox" />  <label for="LoginForm_rememberMe">Remember me next time</label>  <div class="errorMessage" id="LoginForm_rememberMe_em_" style="display:none"></div> </div>

 <div class="row buttons">
  <input type="submit" name="yt0" value="Login" /> </div>

</form></div><!-- form -->
```

---

And this is my code to send a post to the web server.
Please let me know how I can fix it.
Best.

```
package com.*************;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class BakeryLogin {
private String cookie;
private static final String ENCODING = "utf-8";
String usernameParam = "LoginForm[username]";
String passwordParam = "LoginForm[password]";
String nextUrlParam = "next_url=";


public BakeryLogin(){
    cookie = "";
}

public void loginBakery(String bakeryUrl, String username, String password) throws AuthenticateException, IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    PrintWriter pWriter = null;

    URL url = new URL(bakeryUrl);
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
    uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "ja");
    uc.setDoOutput(true);

    try{

        pWriter = new PrintWriter(uc.getOutputStream());
        pWriter.print(usernameParam+"=hogehoge&"+passwordParam+"=fugafuga");
        pWriter.close();


//            StringBuilder parameter = new StringBuilder();
//            parameter.append(usernameParam).append(URLEncoder.encode(username, ENCODING)).append('&');
//            parameter.append(passwordParam).append(URLEncoder.encode(password, ENCODING)).append('&');
 //            parameter.append(nextUrlParam).append(URLEncoder.encode("https://www.gsn7.jp/arkyii/index.php/malsum/index", ENCODING));
//
//            URL url = new URL(bakeryUrl);
//            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
//            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
//            connection.setDoOutput(true);
//
//            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
//            writer.write(parameter.toString());
//            writer.flush();

        Map<String, List<String>> headers = uc.getHeaderFields();
        List<String> values = headers.get("Set-Cookie");

        if(values != null)
            for(String value : values){
                cookie += value + ";";
            }

        if(cookie.isEmpty()) {
            throw new AuthenticateException("cannot login");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Cookie:"+ cookie);
        }

    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }catch(MalformedURLException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }catch(IOException e){
        try{
            if(reader != null)
                reader.close();
//                if(writer != null)
//                    writer.close();
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
            }

            throw e;
        }
    }
    public String getCookie(){
        return cookie;
    }


}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to fix.

Comment: key1=value1&key2=value2. You are forgetting the &.

Comment: thank you for your quick responce.I have changed that part like as pWriter.print(usernameParam+"=hogehoge&"+passwordParam+"=fugafuga");
But can't log in yet.
I don't know should I input "name" parameter or "id" parameter of HTML.
Additionally, I have studied that I need to add all parameters of HTML like remember me and submit.
Is it correct?

Comment: Do you mean if you have to send the hidden inputs  too? If there is both an id and name attribut in an input you probably have to use the id. But try out if you wish.

Comment: Yes. Soory for my english. inside of <div class="form">, there are also name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" and  name="yt0". Sould I input it as the parameter?

Comment: Please read what i said: i think you have to send the `hidden` inputs too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! It works for me after the input of hidden parameters.